# Quickly write files made by MultipleTextOutputFormat to cloud store (Azure, S3, etc)

Tags: azure, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, apache-spark

I have a Spark job that takes data from a Hive table, transforms it, and eventually gives me an RDD containing keys of filenames and values of that file's content. I then pass that onto a custom OutputFormat that creates individual files based on those keys. The end result is about 20 million files, each file being about 1-10MB in size.

My issue is now efficiently writing those files to my end destination. I can't put them in HDFS because 20 million small files will quickly grind HDFS to a halt. If I attempt to write directly to my cloud store it goes very slowly as it appears that each task will upload each file it gets sequentially. I'm interested in hearing about any technique I can use to speed up this process such that files will be uploaded with as much parallelization as possible.

Comment: 20M * 5MB = 100TB of cloud storage.  Is that correct?  That's a lot of network traffic...

Comment: Files above 5MB are generally outliers. Most files tend to be under 1MB, and I'm planning on also utilizing compression (likely Bzip2). After compression, I generally see sizes no greater than 400GB.